# Import data into nvd3 chart and parse the date

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to get the following previous answer to work with a line chart.

[Is it possible to load csv data to nvd3 library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232820/is-it-possible-to-load-csv-data-to-nvd3-library)

I've got the following data to read correctly, however I've hit a wall when trying to parse the Year and Month in using the d3.time parser.

I want to replace the data when I've have a new tsv files, and so I'm looking for a solution which means I don't have to hard code the data into the script every time.

Please please could someone have a look at this jsfiddle - I can't get it to import! I fear I've made a bit of mess with it trying to bring disparate pieces of code together...

http://jsfiddle.net/ComputerSaysNo/uKRe4/2/

This are my data in a tsv:

```
date    A   B   C
201211  72.96541502 82.29955774 15.4213447
201212  52.39325028 84.38944914 14.6014445
201301  51.8616189  81.22953625 12.6544011
201302  60.82223642 80.7554822  11.6052246
201303  90.69965906 74.18499443 10.3059851
201304  24.84915961 78.13503059 19.9208075
201305  26.21120198 79.68013471 8.7695338
201306  50.9979265  83.03684147 7.819079
```

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks - Ryan.

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't support external files. Something like https://vida.io/ is better for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff I've copies it across to here: https://vida.io/documents/bJZos42daRRuRjcpE

Comment: Well the code you have there is nowhere near even compiling. The parse format you would need for the date is "%Y%m" though.